# How can I replace the originating e-mail adress in Azure Api Management Service?

Tags: settings, azure-api-management, email-notifications, email-templates

In Api Management Service, when someone subscribes to an Api, they gey a mail from a no-reply address. By default, this mail is something like "apim-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com", I changed this in de settings to "no-reply@myorganization.com".

[image]

But now when a user receives an email, both these addresses are listed as the sender address. How do I fix it to only display my custom address and remove the default one (circled in red)?

[image]

I tried looking in the mail templates to see if it was present there, but it wasn't.
I tried finding a solution in Microsoft documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you wanted to change the "Mailfrom" header to a value of your choice. Currently it is not possible. The "MailFrom" header contains information about the actual sender of the email since APIM sends the mail you will not be able to remove apim-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com due to security issues.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was something like this and now that's confirmed.